# ArcGis usage on Map UI of Android

Tags: android, google-maps, arcgis

I want to implement Map SDK on Android Project to show Birds/Predator Region.
Which sdk is better between ArcGIS and Google Map library to make coloring range and border lines in specified area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually ArcGIS library is used for 3D Map Rendering and make Coloring on Plain of Maps.
ArcGis is preferred to implement on Android 3D Map layers and it has advantage such as online web layers and offline (tpk file).

Comment: Thanks! Sounds great!